# ubuntu subdomain port forwarding

Tags: ubuntu, subdomain, port-forwarding, docker

I have a ubuntu server with two docker containers. The first one is running lamp and the second container is running a blog. 
currently the blog is accessible on mydomain.com:82 (mydomain.com points to the lamp container on port 80 by default).
i've created A record for blog.mydomain.com to point to the ip of the server. now how do i forward the traffic from blog.mydomain.com to point to mydomain.com:82 where the blog can be accessed.

**solution**

i enabled **proxy** and **proxy_http** modules in apache, 
created a new virtual server in apache with the following config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName blog.mydomain.com
ProxyPass / http://mydomain.com:82/
</VirtualHost>
```

now http://blog.mydomain.com correctly renders content from http://mydomain.com:82 without modifying the url and redirecting

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port

Still answered here, or replace with nginx and listen on server specific name only.